# Save Podcast on iPhone without Downloading

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, podcasts, podcasts.app

I've been using the Podcasts app and I'd like to be able to mark in some way the episodes that I really like. I was saving them but I realized that they get downloaded if I do that, which causes space issues.

Is there a way to save a podcast without actually downloading it? I'm open to other apps that are a reasonable replacement and can achieve what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You could **mark as unplayed** but there doesn't appear to be anything like the heart in Music.